# Como puedo eliminar los caracteres alfabéticos y realizar el calculo?

Tags: python

Tengo un script de Python y  a veces necesito arreglar una String y solo dejar disponible los números el problema viene que quiero hacer que si le paso `Hola 123-3+8/4*2` y que remplace los espacios caracteres alfabéticos y solo deje los números y los operadores `+, -, *, /` y luego transformar los que devuelva el calculo ya hecho
hasta ahora use esto:

```
import re
def FIXINT(Value:str):
    FixedINT = re.sub('\D', '', Value)
    return FixedINT

Arreglar = "Hola 123+23*4/2"
print(FIXINT(Arreglar))
```

esto devuelve: `1232342`
y quiero que devuelva el calculo que seria `169`

Comment: Seria `124`? No `169`?

Comment: si solo que tenia copiado otro numero perdon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usaremos una expresión regular para reconocer la expresión algebraica:

```
patron = re.compile(r"([0-9+-/*]+)")
```

Luego, dado un string

```
Arreglar = "Hola 123+23*4/2"
```

Podemos pedir todas las expresiones algebraicas reconocidas. Si hay al menos una, `findall` retorna una lista (o `None`, si no hay ninguna).

```
m = patron.findall(Arreglar)
```

Suponiendo que solo hay una expresión, la puedo calcular usando la función `eval`, que recibe y ejecuta un código fuente Python. Como una expresión es un código válido, *no problem*

```
x = eval(m[0])
```

Resultado:

```
print(x)
```

produce:

```
169.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hay que notar que si el calculo a hacer puede ser ingresado por el usuario, usar eval puede conllevar comportamientos inesperados (como el uso de la potenciación). Sin embargo, los riesgos son reducidos debido a que solo admite numeros y signos.

Comment: Además, puedes usar la expresión `re.sub(r'[^0-9+-*/]', '', Value)`

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado a la hora de usar exec, eval o cualquier otra cosa que pueda ejecutar código python a partir de una cadena. Ya que si el código puede ser escrito por el usuario con poca o ninguna restricción podría ingresar cualquier código inesperado.

Comment: @DanteS. Si el uso de exec y eval es bastante peligroso y mas en este proyecto ya que se utilizan los 2 asique tengo que mirar con lupa para no liarla

Comment: para evaluar la expresion entera solo use `m = "".join(m)`